# Spring boot Hibernate data source exception null exception on application start up

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

Getting

> ERROR [SpringApplication] Application startup failed
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myEntityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [com/employees/service/config/DBConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean
>
> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException     at
> org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.hbm.ModelBinder$AbstractPluralAttributeSecondPass.bindCollectionElement(ModelBinder.java:3554)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]     at
> org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.hbm.ModelBinder$AbstractPluralAttributeSecondPass.doSecondPass(ModelBinder.java:3133)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]     at
> org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1696)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]     at
> org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1664)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]     at
> org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:287)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]     at
> org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:904)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]     at
> org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:935)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]     at
> org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60)

for code

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.employees")
@Bean
public DataSource myDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}

@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean myEntityManagerFactory() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean employees = createEntityManagerFactory(
        myDataSource(), "Employees",
        MyMapping.MAPPINGS);
    return employees;
}

@Bean
public EntityManager myEntityManager(@Qualifier("myEntityManagerFactory")
    EntityManagerFactory emf) {
    return entityManager(emf);
}

@Bean
public JpaTransactionManager myTransactionManager(@Qualifier("myEntityManagerFactory")
    EntityManagerFactory emf) {
    return transactionManager(emf);
}

@Bean
public TransactionHelper myTransactionHelper(
    @Qualifier("myTransactionManager")
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager) {
    TransactionHelper transactionHelper = new TransactionHelper();
    transactionHelper.setPlatformTransactionManager(transactionManager);
    return transactionHelper;
}

// Common methods
private LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean createEntityManagerFactory(
    DataSource dataSource, String persistenceUnitName, String[] mappings) {
    MyLocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory
        = new MyLocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    entityManagerFactory.setDataSource(dataSource);
    entityManagerFactory.setPersistenceUnitName(persistenceUnitName);
    entityManagerFactory.setPackagesToScan("com.employees.domain");
    JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    entityManagerFactory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    entityManagerFactory.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());

    if (mappings != null) {
        entityManagerFactory.setMappingResources(mappings);
    }
    return entityManagerFactory;
}

private JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
    return transactionManager;
}

private EntityManager entityManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
    return SharedEntityManagerCreator.createSharedEntityManager(emf);
}

@Bean
@Primary
public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
    return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
}

private Properties additionalProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "none");
    //        properties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy",
        "com.employees.domain.hibernate.BackwardsCompatibleImplicitNamingStrategy");
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect");
    return properties;
}

@Bean public TraceProperties traceProperties() {
    TraceProperties traceProperties = new TraceProperties();
    Set<TraceProperties.Include> includes = new HashSet<>();
    includes.addAll(Arrays.asList(TraceProperties.Include.values()));
    traceProperties.setInclude(includes);
    return traceProperties;
}
```

Comment: what's the package where you put entities POJOs?

Comment: As you are using spring boot I would suggest you take advantage of `Auto configuration` for your database. You just have to add the `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` dep. to your pom.xml then use spring boot out-of-the-box properties to configure your database in the application.properties files: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html#common-application-properties-data

Comment: I am migrating a core java to spring boot so cannot use auto configuration

Comment: Package where my POJOs are is com.employes.domain

Comment: I was not able to reproduce your issue. It works fine for me. Though a suggestion: make your data source properties are well-read from `@ConfigurationProperties`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, this issue was related to hibernate mappings. There was one .hbm file that had a nested table in it or an association that was not defined when creating database connection entity manager factory.